# msf4j response image got Improperly closed variable

Tags: java, microservices, mustache, msf4j

i use msf4j with mustache for my project service and get problem when returning an image (image/png) as a response entity. here the code:

```
String img = MustacheTemplateEngine.render('path/to/image.png',null);
return Response.ok().type(MediaType.valueOf("image/png")).entity(img).build();
```

I realize mustache render only return string so there is no way to get image object as response. Is there another way to make response as image/png?

Comment: Can't you use an approach like https://github.com/wso2/msf4j/blob/master/core/src/test/java/org/wso2/msf4j/service/TestMicroservice.java#L382

Comment: actually i need  the image show in my web microservice

Comment: did you try the approach I suggested? It outputs an image from the service